# How to add special constraints while creating table DDL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

I want to put some special constraints over my values in the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
{
  id varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

  first_special varchar(8), <- I want it to have max of 8 symbols with no spaces in it

  second_special float  <- I want it to have precision of 2 decimal points after the '.'
}
```

EDIT:

The platform is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Don't use `float` (or `double` or something similar). Those approximate types and what you store there is not necessarily the same that you retrieve later. Use `numeric` or `number` or whatever the name in your DBMS is.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle (and I think in all dbs) the second one is easy.

```
second_special NUMBER(5,2) -- The max number would be 999.99
```